Removing Shading Crease
I want to understand where is this shading crease coming from more than fix the problem.
I tried merging vertices, checking for faces behind this shape, removing custom normals, reset vectors with Alt + N, flatten the faces around the problem, flatten the problem, checking for ngons and tris.


Blend File

Can you show this mesh in edit mode so we can see the general structure?

the first pic is edit mode if i'm not mistaken..

This is likely because that face is not planar. It is possible for four points to be nonplanar, so when that happens to a face (as seems to be the case here), the render engine quietly bends it along one of the diagonals, chosen arbitrarily. In other words, a render engine actually only draws triangles, and it is creating an extra edge as shown in yellow:

Thus, the sharpness you are seeing is because the normals from the two large faces are being blended very quickly over the tiny width of that new slim triangle between the edge you can see and the one you can’t.
